# How to install two python versions in one computer

Tags: python, version, curses

I have `Python 3.10 (64-bit)` on my computer. And I use `VS Code`. I need to install `Python 3.8 (64-bit)` because I need to work with `curses` and it only works with `Python 3.8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you can use [virtual environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-and-virtual-environments) for example using [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/).

1. Create a virtual environment for python 3.8. In the project folder run the following command

```sh
    conda create --name "your-desired-environment-name" python="python-version"
```

e.g. to create a virtual environment for Python 3.8, run

```sh
   conda create --name env_python3.8 python=3.8
```

2. Activate the created environment

```sh
    conda activate env_python3.8
```

Then, in visual studio Code, you can easily switch from a virtual environment to another. That depends on the project that you are working on.

The following [How-to guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/selecting-a-python-environment-for-a-project?view=vs-2022) from VS Code can also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual environments are used for that.
I use [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) to manage my python versions.

After installing it, you can simply create an environment with python 3.8 like this:

```sh
conda create -n python38 python=3.8
```

Afterwards you can activate the create environment like this

```sh
conda activate python38
```

And install a wide variety of packages like so:

```sh
conda install matplotlib pandas numpy
```

Comment: can you tell more about it

Comment: I edited my answer. Which IDE do you use to run python? If you use PyCharm (which I can recommend) you can simply pick which python environment you want to use for your project.

Comment: I use vs code as my main text editor